# Salesforce Profile clone

Tags: custom-profile

I have created a profile, Cloning from others profile around 1 year ago. Now my requirement is to identify the created profile is cloned from which profile?

How do I know it is cloned from which profile?
Please Help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to determine programmatically which profile a profile was cloned from. Once cloned, it is a separate record with no link to the original. You can name the profiles to keep track, but that is a manual discipline, not something you can query later.